# Does call to setState function in react native, only works in arrow function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I need your help to explain about this react native code.

Below Code, when updateState function is written using arrow function, code is work perfectly

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Home extends Component {
   state = {
      myState: 'aaaaa'
   }
   updateState = () => {
      this.setState({ myState: 'The state is updated' })
    }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text onPress = {this.updateState}>
               UPDATE:{this.state.myState}
            </Text>            
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

but when I change the updateState function, using ordinary function (not arrow function) like code below, my state is not changed when text are pressed.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Home extends Component {
   state = {
      myState: 'aaaaa'
   }
   updateState (){
      this.setState({ myState: 'The state is updated' })
    }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text onPress = {this.updateState}>
               UPDATE:{this.state.myState}
            </Text>            
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

My question is, does call to setState function must using arrow function?

Appreciate for your help about this matter.

Thank you

Comment: you should leave it with an arrow function. the methods need react components `this` bound to them. Arrow function definitions is a clean implementation of doing just that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use without arrow should add `bind` in `constructor()`

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myState: 'aaaaa'
    }
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }

  updateState(){
    this.setState({ myState: 'The state is updated' })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Text onPress = {this.updateState}>
            UPDATE:{this.state.myState}
         </Text>            
      </View>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers, and by [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer to any
question you ask.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `function`, you'd need to bind `this` in the constructor so that function `updateState` refers to the class when referring to `this`. Try the following:

```
constructor() {
  this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

On every render, reference to the function is created.

So, to avoid that, bind OR arrow function are used.

I call a function like this:

functionA = () => {}

TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.functionA()}

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot!!